# Get blank activity after using navigateupfromsametask

Tags: android

I have two activities here. First activity only has a listview. After I click an item in the listview, the second activity is opened.If I click phone's hard back button, everything is fine, I'll go back to first activity and I can see my listview. However, if I click the back button on the action bar, navigateupfromsametask is called, I go back to the first activity, but I can't see the listview. I already set the first activity to be the parent activity of the second one in the manifest. Does anyone know why I can't see the listview? Thanks!

Comment: navigateupfromsametask i presume starts a fresh activity, try debugging to determine whats going wrong, or if the adapter is set correctly.

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462456/returning-from-an-activity-using-navigateupfromsametask?answertab=votes#tab-top) if it helps

Comment: Happy to help! Hpy coding!