# Up navigation and saved instance data

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

An app has 2 activities, A and B.

A has instance data that is saved

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("foo", 0);
}
```

and A has

```
int bar;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        bar = savedInstanceState.getInt("foo");
    } else {
        bar = -1;
    }
}
```

to restore the data.

Activity B has the actionbar enabled and

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // ...
}
```

to enable up navigation.  Also A is listed as the parent activity of B in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

When a user navigates from A to B `onSaveInstanceState` is called and if they navigate back to `A` using the back button activity A correctly restores it's saved information.

However when the user navigates from A to B `onSaveInstanceState` is called and then up navigation is used to return to A the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` is passed `null` even though information was saved.

How do I get up navigation to pass the the Bundle created in `onSaveInstanceState`?

Comment: Looks like this was a duplicate, after poking around some more I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16147110/2474498) answer which cleared things up.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I have an expandableListView loaded in Activity A and pass it to activity B. When I use the Android Back Button the ExpandableListView is retained but when I use "UP" navigation the expandableListView is destroyed and I have an empty activity.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue - I simply wanted to have two activities A and B, where A is the parent of B. When you are in B and click the Up button, you return to A and in `onCreate()` you restore your data from the Bundle. However, the bundle is always `null`.

In most cases, people recommend setting `android:launchMode="singleTop"` for the activity in the manifest. This is, actually, not necessarily a desired behaviour, because it simply means that when you click the Up button, the parent will not be recreated. You might find this OK, but in my case I definitely wanted to have the parent recreated to mirror some changes in the DB.

Other solutions say to attach a listener to the Up button and add this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This achieved no effect for me. I don't actually understand what this code is supposed to do.

Still, I think I found an answer to the question in another post. Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780369/recreating-activity-state-after-clicking-back-button?rq=1).

It's said:

> When you press back, the Activity is destroyed and the data it had is lost. After this you will always get null in the bundle as a new, fresh instance is being created when you reopen the app.
>
> The Bundle savedInstanceState is used when the activity is being recreated due to some changes (like rotation), or because it was paused in the background for a long time.
>
> If you want to persist some data, consider SharedPreferences for small stuff, or maybe a database (SQLite, Realm) or files for large stuff.

I guess that the approach with the bundle is simply not the way Android expects us to do it. You should use a `SharedPreferences` object and save your `foo` variable inside it.

Answer (score 0):

As @castafiore said, it depends on what's behaviour want your app have. In my case, I solved this issue by adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.