# savedInstanceState in parent activity is null when up button in child activity is pressed

Tags: java, android, onsaveinstancestate, up-button

I have a problem with the usage of the Up button in my application. There are many posts that I already read dealing with similar problems, but none of them addresses the same issue that I want to solve.

I have two activities - `A` and `B`. 
A displays a list of tasks for a chosen category from an SQLite db. Each task belongs to a category, therefore, A has a private variable `topicId` passed from an Intent (it acts as a filter). When I click on a task, it opens activity B which allows you to edit it. B has an Up button which leads you back to A (the list with the tasks).

Since A gets the topicId from an intent, When I click the Up button in B, there is no intent in A and the topicId is -1 by default. I thought it's easy to preserve the id - just save it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("topicId", this.TOPIC_ID);
}
```

In the onCreate() method I used:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
    this.TOPIC_ID = savedInstanceState.getInt("topicId");
}
```

However, the savedInstanceState that gets passed to onCreate() is always `null`.
I put Log in A's lifecycle methods to see what happens.

1. I'm in A - `onCreate()` runs and the bundle is null
2. I click on a task in the list (a Fragment, that's loaded in a ViewPager)
3. `onSaveInstanceState()` runs and saves my Id
4. Now I'm in B and I click the Up button (not the back key on the phone)
5. It runs A's `onDestroy()`, then A's `onCreate()` and the bundle is `null`!

Can someone tell me why the Bundle in `onCreate()` is null in this case? I've set B's parent activity to be A in the manifest.xml. I also read a solution which supposes you to add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in the manifest for A.

This is, however, not what I want - if it is set to singleTop, the parent activity does NOT get destroyed when you click the Up button. I want to have it destroyed and recreated, because in B I make changes to a task which I want to see immediately reloaded from the DB in A when I click Up.

I'd appreciate if someone tells me why Android passes a `null` bundle to `onCreate()`. I already tried adding this code to B and it didn't work:

```
Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057607/up-navigation-and-saved-instance-data) post is about the same issue , but it hasn't been answered for 4 years...

I will post code if you need it. I don't want to be too overwhelming in the beginning.

**Edit**

After some more search I found this solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780369/recreating-activity-state-after-clicking-back-button?rq=1)

It's said:

> When you press back, the Activity is destroyed and the data it had is lost. After this you will always get null in the bundle as a new, fresh instance is being created when you reopen the app.
>
> The Bundle savedInstanceState is used when the activity is being recreated due to some changes (like rotation), or because it was paused in the background for a long time.
>
> If you want to persist some data, consider SharedPreferences for small stuff, or maybe a database (SQLite, Realm) or files for large stuff.

As far as I understand, the Bundle is used by Android only in some specific cases, like when you turn off/on the screen, click the Home button or change the screen orientation. In cases like mine, you have to rely on some other features like the `SharedPreferences` class. I welcome people with some more advanced knowledge than me to shed some more light on the matter.

Comment: How did you started activity B? SaveInstanceState is something Android do when it needs memory and kills activities to free up memory/

Comment: In activity A I have a Fragment with a RecyclerView and inside it multiple CardViews for the tasks. I have attached an onClickListener on the tasks and when one is clicked, the following code handles it:
    `@Override`
    `public void onItemClick(int id) {`
        `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CreateTaskActivity.class);`
        `intent.putExtra(CreateTaskActivity.EXTRA_TASK_ID, id);`
        `startActivity(intent);`
     `}`

Comment: what is the android:launchMode of activity b?

Comment: It is not specified, so it must be the default value `standard`.

Comment: the back button destroy an activity, the best method is to use SharedPreferences for this.