# How to resume activity instead of restart when going "up" from action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-navigation

I have **two** activities. Say `Activity A` and `Activity B`.

From `Activity A` I click a button to launch `Activity B` This is the code I use for this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

---

Now at this point, I am in `Activity B`. On the on create method of `Activity B`, I enable the up button.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_news);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //Here//
}
```

and on the event handle for the "up" button, i have this code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

---

Now I decide to go back to `Activity A` I click the up button in the action bar which looks like this: [image]

Now the problem is, when I click the "up button", it goes back to `Activity A` which is fine, but it **restarts** it. How can make it stop restarting? I just want it to **resume**.

When I use my hardware back button, it works as expected. i.e it goes to `Activity A` and resumes it instead of restarting it.

I want my activity to resume because on that activity, I download some string online and so I don't want it to keep re downloading the data when a users goes from **Activity B -> Activity A**

---

**Edit** My manifest file for `Activity B` section looks like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.ActivityB"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_view_news"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.android.ActivityA">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.android.ActivityA" />
</activity>
```

---

**Edit 2 [Answer]**
Ok so, this was pretty unexpected but in my AndroidManifest.xml, in the Activity A section, I had to add the following line liner. `android:launchMode="singleTop"` so it now looks like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.ActivityA"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:launchMode="singleTop"> //**HERE**//
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

[The explanation to this is given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462456/returning-from-an-activity-using-navigateupfromsametask/16147110#16147110)

Comment: are you declare ActivityA as Parent activity ?

Comment: @mohammedmomn I believe I have done so. Check my `AndroidManifest.xml` I have posted at the end of my question

Comment: not sure if this is what you need but you can take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16147110/3286163

Comment: @singularhum Damn that was the solution the whole time! Thanks for leading me there!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Should've added as an answer instead of a comment.. but here you go so you can accept if you want so others can see if necessary.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16147110/3286163

Basically, to summarize the android will always recreate the activity unless you specify it not to with

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Note: it will not work if the returning activity is not on the top of the back stack as mentioned in the reference.

For anyone else, please upvote the answer in the url instead of mine if you find this useful.

Comment: "..please upvote the answer in the url instead of mine if you find this useful." Wow, what a guy!

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same outcome programatically

```
Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
upIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
```