# Android up button with Viewpager: go back to the previously selected fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm having some problems with navigation and the up button of the activity. I have two tabs implemented with `Viewpager` in one activity and then another activity which is loaded from the previous one. When the user clicks the phone's back button or the activity's up button, I want to go back to the previously selected tab and fragment of the first activity.

So far I've been able to do it for the back button, with `onSaveInstanceState` and the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    bundle.putInt("currentPage", mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        int page = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentPage", 0);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
        getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(page);
    }
}
```

Why is this not working for the up button? What do I have to do?

Any help is appreciated and sorry if this is an issue easy to solve, but I'm rather new to the Android programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution at [Returning from an activity using navigateUpFromSameTask()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462456/returning-from-an-activity-using-navigateupfromsametask/16147110#16147110). savedInstanceState was null when the activity was recreated. To avoid so, the launch mode of the activity has to be declared as singleTop in the Android manifest.