# How to transfer data in the previous activity by using the back button in the action bar?

Tags: android

I did a back button by writing in the manifest file(like there http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

```
<activity android:name=".Activity2"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"
            />

    </activity>
```

How do I transfer data from Activity 2 when returning to MainActivity?Or there is a better way to make back button in action bar?

Comment: Shared Preferences?  Singleton?  Lots of ways.

Comment: Well, you could also launch the parent activity with an intent and put the data in extras. Check the available flags so the activity starts in the correct mode.

Answer (score 1):

First, invoke `Activity2` from `MainActivity` using `Activity.startActivityForResult()`.

In `Activity2`, once the user has done the action that will set up the data you want, call `Activity.setResult()`.  You can set a resultCode of `RESULT_OK` and pass an `Intent` here containing the `Parcelable` data you want to return.

Finally, you will override `Activity.onActivityResult()` in your `MainActivity`.  This will be called when `Activity2` finishes.  Here you you will receive the resultCode of `RESULT_OK` and you can access the `Intent` that was set up by your `Activity2`.

See this link [Starting Activities and Getting Results | Activity | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to use `startActivityForResult()` to start the SecondActivity and use `onActivityResult()` to receive the data from SecondActivity to the FirstActivity.

Refer here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

From `MainActivity` you can start `Activity2` using `startActivityForResult()` - then in the second Activity you can set the result that you want to be sent back to the `MainActivity` when the user clicks the Back Button. You do something like:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,resultIntent );
```

Alternatively, you could override `getParentActivityIntent ()` (or `getSupportParentActivityIntent()` if using Support Library) in `Activity2` like:

```
@Override
public Intent getParentActivityIntent () {
    Intent intent = super.getParentActivityIntent();
    //here you put the data that you want to send back - could be Serializable/Parcelable, etc
    intent.putExtra("result",result);
    return intent;
}
```

You can check out the selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android), and explore some options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462456/returning-from-an-activity-using-navigateupfromsametask)

Comment: How can i track when user click the back button?

Comment: You can override the `onBackPressed` method like this            `@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // user clicked back button? Do something here (but do not change the expected behavior as that might confuse the user...
}`