# How to restore activity data after navigating back from child activity?

Tags: android

After this code in MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

then when a button is clicked in OtherActivity    `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` happens, so the app returns to MainActivity. But I don't think the data is restored from previously, and I don't think it should've been destroyed because onDestroy() wasn't called right?

Comment: Can you share what NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this); does? maybe it starts a new instance of your MainActivity instead of going back!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html

Comment: Is your MainActivity `singleTop` ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: [Returning from an activity using navigateUpFromSameTask()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462456/returning-from-an-activity-using-navigateupfromsametask)

`android:launchMode="singleTop"` in the manifest prevents a new instance of the activity from being created.